# Efficient Method to Implement Binary Sorted Tree in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, sorting, binary-tree

I'm working on a project where I need to maintain a sorted list of values. The primary use of this data structure would be to quickly look up the closest value to another given value. I also will be frequently inserting values, so sorting at the time of lookup is impractical unless I keep running a sort.  Considering the requirements, I believe a binary sorted tree might be the most suitable data structure for this task.

However, my primary concern is the performance. As I'm working with JavaScript, I'm aware that native Javascript functions are often faster than custom implementations due to the optimizations provided by the Javascript engine.

I've considered using an array and keep it sorted with `Array.sort()`. When I need to find the closest value, I would perform a binary search on the array. I've also considered implementing a binary search tree or self-balancing binary search tree (like an AVL tree or a red-black tree).

While the first approach is simpler, the cost of sorting the array every time an element is added could be significant if the list is large. On the other hand, while the second approach has better theoretical time complexity, I'm concerned that the JavaScript implementation could be slower due to the overhead of managing the tree structure.

What's the better approach in terms of performance, or is there a better option?  Are there other data structures or methods you would recommend that can provide efficient insertion and closest value lookup?

My anticipated number of values could reach up to 100k, and I'll be doing the lookups about 500k times per run.

Thanks

Comment: How many values are being inserted in each run?

Comment: Maybe up to 200k max.  Probably closer to 100k.

Comment: You'll need to [benchmark this yourself](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) in your target environment.

Comment: Also try a,b-trees, not just binary trees

Comment: What is the performance if you don't call `sort`, but assume the array was sorted before the new insertion, and then use binary search to find the insertion index and insert with `splice`? For 100k items that should be quite fast...

Comment: @trincot yes, exactly what was written in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76495367/112968)

Comment: My question was to umop

Answer (score 0):

If you store your elements in a (pre-sorted) list, then you can use [*binary search*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to find the index where to insert your new element. Finding the correct index with binary search is O(log(n)) – that's at most 17 steps for a 100k list. You don't have to re-sort the whole list with this approach, only find the correct index, then insert the item.

Comment: You still need to move `O(n)` elements one index to the right for inserting a new element somewhere in the middle